# Creating full-width horizontal menu in CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I force my tabs to take all the remaining space in the menu? so, adjust the spaces between the tabs according to the number of tabs.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="lien_menu"><br>Onglet0 loooooooog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="lien_menu"><br>Onglet1</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my current code :
http://jsfiddle.net/Fxy8r/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question or add an illustration?

Comment: Is this a horizontal menu or a vertical menu?

Comment: You are using unordered lists but are not defining how each list item should display.  There is where you can achieve the results you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

Add the following CSS:

```
#menu {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

#menu ul {
  display: table-row;
}

#menu ul li {
 display: table-cell;
}
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fxy8r/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu {
  width:100%;
}
#menu ul {
  width:inherit;
}
#menu ul li {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
```